# Best way to create a sandbox area on my asp .net host

Tags: asp.net, web-hosting

I would like to create a sandbox area on my hosting provider that only the client can see. For example the production website would be at www.domain.com. However, would it be possible to create a sandbox version of the website at www.domain.com/sandbox and only provide access to the client?

If so, what is the best method? Do I manually have to create a login page etc in the sandbox folder? Or, can I publish the test website in the sandbox area and restrict access through my hosting provider?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally a sandbox/staging/test version of your production site would be a complete duplicate of your production deployment, not just the login page.

You'd have a separate copy of the application and the database, and then serve it via another hostname/IP address or on an entirely different machine.

For instance, you could have www.domain.com and test.domain.com, each with the own isolated version of the software.  This way your client can play as much as they want in the sandbox without fear of damaging the production environment.

To restrict access you could use access control lists in IIS to restrict the sandbox to a specific ip address (or range), or enable basic support on it with a username/password required security.

Comment: I'm working on the same project to create a sandbox simulation using Asp.net so I know he will need to clone database too, then [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48238291/to-create-some-customized-sql-tables-clone-by-script) Q&A in Stack Over Flow would help him out.